# What maintenance tasks should I run on my MS-SQL 2008/2012 servers?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, maintenance

The servers are using database mirroring for high-availability running SQL server standard on newer hardware.

The existing plans were setup by a DBA many years ago and are using the built in maintenance tools available in the UI.

Daily:
Full Backup of ALL databases
Transaction log backups every 15 minutes for user databases
Check database integrity of all databases including indexes
Clean up history
Cleanup backups

Weekly:
Reorganize indexes on all databases - include tables and views and compact large objects
Update statistics on all database - include tables and views, update all existing stats with Full scan

On Sunday mornings approximately 1 hour after the reorganize task the server becomes unresponsive and I have to stop the SQL service to initiate a failover to the mirror server.  I assume that the reorganize or update stats is causing the issues.  Wondering if I should be doing the compact routine at all and/or running the reorganize on every table (system and user).

How can I modify my tasks to reduce stress on the server but still perform the proper maintenance?

Comment: If that was set up many years ago, check whether the hardware is good enough. Seriously. Companies grow - sometimes you just need to throw some hardware at it. Alternatively you could stretch out the sunday window. Maybe reorganize takes more than 1 hour now?

Comment: @TomTom - It is running on newer hardware than when the plans were setup, but the number of databases has grown and some databases have millions of records.

Comment: Time to consider splitting then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what you're using for maintenance, however...

It's usually not necessary to reorganize indexes on *all* databases.  Some of them will need it and some won't.  You could probably switch to something like [Ola Hallengren's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/), which will check and see if the indexes need it first.  I'd recommend something like that.

You might also want to consider what (if anything) changed in the environment.  Do you have more databases than you did years ago?  Did something happen to make the reindex job more painful, or was it always like this and you only noticed when you took over?

Comment: The databases are setup on AWS ec2 instances (i2.2xlarge) whereas they were previously running on dedicated hardware.  I will see about only running the reorganization on certain databases.  Since the plans were setup a long time ago, I assume there are now better practices to consider, but not being a DBA, it is easy to get lost in the sea of information.